# How do I partially apply (or curry) a higher order apply with generic types?

Tags: scala, generics

### TL;DR

I think my TL;DR is how do I partial generic functions? But, I've added details to try and help. I've tried Googling, but I'm fairly new to Scala, so I think there's a term or two that I'm missing.

### Background

I'm trying to cut down boilerplate a bit and I've run into a situation where I can't seem to figure out the Scala syntax. I have a wrapper around Future that looks like:

```
// Wrapper for a block that sends timing data to statsd using a Stats class
object Timed {
  def apply[A](key: String, maybeStat: Option[Stats] = None)(block: => A): A = {
    val stat = maybeStat.getOrElse(Stats())
    val start = DateTime.now()
    val out = block
    stat.time(key, new Duration(start, DateTime.now()).getMillis)
    out
  }
}

object TimedFuture {
  def apply[A](key: String, maybeStat: Option[Stats] = None)(block: => A)(
    implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext
  ): Future[A] = Future {
    Timed(key, maybeStat)(block)
  }
}
```

I then have services that look like:

```
class ThingsServiceImpl @Inject() (
  private val database: Database,
  private implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext
) extends ThingsService {
  private val stat = Stats.withPrefix("services.things")

  override def findThings(ids: Long*): Future[Seq[Thing]] = TimedFuture("find_things", Option(stat)) {
    // Find the things using a sync DB connection :-/
  }
}
```

I want to remove the awkward additional argument of `Option(stat)` to all `TimedFuture` calls by adding a line something like:

```
// Context
) extends ThingsService {
  private val stat = Stats.withPrefix("services.things")
// End context

  private val TimedFuturePartialed = TimedFuture(_, Option(stat))
```

So that I can use it like:

```
override def findThings(ids: Long*): Future[Seq[Thing]] = TimedFuturePartialed("find_things") {
```

The goal here is I want to get times in statsd that look like: `"services.things.find_things"` w/o repeating myself so much.

The thing I tried above and IntelliJ's auto typing showed me:

```
private val TimedFutureP: (String) => (Nothing) => Future[Nothing] = TimedFuture(_, Option(stat))
```

But, that type isn't generic enough.

Comment: Finally wound up adding, `def fromStats[A](stat: Stats)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): String => (=> A) => Future[A] = apply[A](_, Option(stat))`, which allows creation like: `private def TimedFutureP[A] = TimedFuture.fromStats[A](stat)` and usage as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `TimedFuturePartialed` a generic method (or object with a generic `apply` method, same thing almost).

```
private def TimedFuturePartialed[A](block: => A) = TimedFuture(block, Option(stat))
```

This way `block` will not be inferred as `Nothing`. That is, if you want to keep it generic, you cannot lose the type parameter.

Alternatively, if all you're trying to do is avoid explicitly passing around `Option[Stats]`, you can try making it implicit.

```
object TimedFuture {
  def apply[A](key: String)(block: => A)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, maybeStat: Option[Stats] = None): Future[A] = Future {
    Timed(key, maybeStat)(block)
  }
}
```

This will work okay if each of your objects has it's own `Option[Stats]` defined, but may cause problems (i.e. ambiguous implicits, surprising results from incorrect resolution) if you have more than one of these floating around for any object.

Comment: Thanks! I wound up w/ almost the same thing after a hint from a coworker. The actual thing I landed on was: `private def TimedFutureP[A]: (String) => (A) => Future[A] = TimedFuture[A](_, Option(stat))`. Giving you the √ since it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: To simplify each service a bit further I've done: `def fromStats[A](stat: Stats): (String) => (A) => Future[A] = apply[A](_, Option(stat))`, which allows, `private def TimedFutureP[A] = TimedFuture.fromStats[A](stat)` in the modules (hiding most of the complexity).

Comment: Err `def fromStats[A](stat: Stats)(key: String)(block: => A)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = 
    apply[A](key, Option(stat))(block)`